# How to resume crawling after last depth I reached when I restart my crawler?

Tags: java, web-crawler, crawler4j

**Hello Everyone**
I am making a web application that crawl lots of pages from a specific website,
I started my crawler4j software with unlimited depth and pages but suddenly it stopped because of internet connection.
Now I want to continue crawling that website and not to fetch the urls I visited before considering I have last pages depth.

> *Note* :  I want some way that not to check my stored url with the urls I will fetch because I don't want to send very much requests to this site.

**Thanks **☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "resumeable" crawling with `crawler4j` by enabling this feature

```
crawlConfig.setResumableCrawling(true);
```

in the given configuration. See the documentation of `crawler4j` [here](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j).

Comment: Great , but how this method work?,what logic it uses?

Comment: If it is enabled, it uses the internal berkley database to store intermediate crawl data (frontier, docid server) in the location you specified by setting the crawl storage folder.